# How can I use query_string to match both nested and non-nested fields at the same time?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a mapping something like this:

```
"email" : {
  "type" : "nested",
  "properties" : {
    "from" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer" : "lowercase_keyword",
      "fielddata" : true
    },
    "subject" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer" : "lowercase_keyword",
      "fielddata" : true
    },
    "to" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer" : "lowercase_keyword",
      "fielddata" : true
    }
  }
},
"textExact" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "analyzer" : "lowercase_standard",
  "fielddata" : true
}
```

I want to use [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to search for matches in both the nested and the non-nested field at the same time, e.g.

```
email.to:foo@example.com AND textExact:bar
```

But I can't figure out how to write a query that will search both fields at once. The following doesn't work, because [`query_string` searches do not return nested documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-nested):

```
"query": {
  "query_string": {
    "fields": [
      "textExact",
      "email.to"
    ],
    "query": "email.to:foo@example.com AND textExact:bar"
  }
}
```

I can write a separate nested query, but that will only search against nested fields. Is there any way I can use `query_string` to match both nested and non-nested fields at the same time?

I am using Elasticsearch 6.8. [Cross-posted](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-use-query-string-to-match-both-nested-and-non-nested-fields-at-the-same-time/288023) on the Elasticsearch forums.

Answer (score 0):

Nested documents can  only be queried with the nested query.

You can follow below two approaches.

**1. You can combine nested and normal query in must clause, which works like "and" for different queries.**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "email",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "email.to": "foo@example.com"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "textExact": "bar"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**2. [copy-to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html#copy-to)**

> The copy_to parameter allows you to copy the values of multiple fields into a group field, which can then be queried as a single field.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "textExact":{
        "type": "text"
      },
      "to_email":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "email":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "to":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "copy_to": "to_email"  --> copies to non-nested field
          },
          "from":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "textExact",
        "to_email"
      ],
      "query": "to_email:foo@example.com AND textExact:bar"
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
"_source" : {
          "textExact" : "bar",
          "email" : [
            {
              "to" : "sdfsd@example.com",
              "from" : "a@example.com"
            },
            {
              "to" : "foo@example.com",
              "from" : "sdfds@example.com"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to do option #1, but unfortunately the query string is input by users, so I would have to use a Lucene parser to split it, which would add a significant amount of complexity. With option #2, you flatten the fields and lose the benefit of having a `nested` field. In your example, if there were also a `from_email` field, the query `to_email:foo@example.com AND from_email:a@example.com AND textExact:bar` would match; maybe that's what the user wants, and maybe not. I'll have to think about it.